# Using three grep commands to sort and alphabetically order

Tags: grep

I created the file ~/firstredhat.txt.

How do I make an alphabetically sorted list of all files underneath the /usr/share/firstboot directory (and its subdirectories) that contain the text redhat, using a case insensitive search?

The files should be listed one per line using absolute references.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: find /usr/share/firstboot -type f -iname '*redhat*' | sort -z | tr '\0' '\n' This is what I have tried and it says the output is wrong for some reason the star sign isn't showing next to the word redhat. It says the out put is wrong

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline feature of the shell and man pages are the key. Try the following.

```
grep -RIHi "redhat" /usr/share/firstboot | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'| sort | uniq
```

Comment: nope it says file does not match output. I thought maybe I was doing something wrong this is what I put grep -RIHi "redhat" /usr/share/firstboot | awk -F ':' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq > ~/firstredhat.txt

Comment: Can anyone offer anymore help with this